# Create tree from js array

Tags: javascript, java, tree

I'm trying to create tree from a list . My data is like ;

```
A-->B-->C-->D-->E..
A-->B-->C-->D-->F..
A-->F-->C-->D-->E..
.
.
.
```

I have all possible data path in array.I want to show this like

```
                     A
                       -B
                         -C
                           -D 
                              -E
                              -F
                       -F
                         -C
                           -D
                             -E
```

How can i create and check with javascript ? I need createTreeFunction :)

```
function parseData(data)
  {


   $.each(data, function (i, p) {
                   var arr = p.split("--->");

                 createTreeFunction(p);

                  });

   };
  function parseData(data)
      {


       $.each(data, function (i, p) {
                       var arr = p.split("--->");

                     createTreeFunction(p);

                      });

   };
```

Comment: Javascript != Java, and it says that in countless places on this website.

Comment: please supply some data which are not invalid (tree wise), or create a loop. please use unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use cases i had invented very useful two Object methods; namely `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` and `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()`. By utilizing these methods this job is nothing more than a single liner JS code. See below...

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                              : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                                 this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
                      : this[a[0]] = a[1];
};

var data = "A-->B-->C-->D-->E\nA-->B-->C-->D-->F\nA-->F-->C-->D-->E",
  datarr = data.split("\n").map(e => e.split("-->")), // get your list in an array
       o = {};
datarr.forEach(a => !o.getNestedValue(...a) && o.setNestedValue(...a,null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(o,null,2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can use at least two different structures for the children for building a tree, one with an array (Solution A) or with an object (Solution B).

The advantage of an array over an object is the direct iteration over the children. With an object, you need to get the keys first and then is an iteration possible.

Otherwise if you know one child, then the access over the key is faster. This is also true for inserting new nodes to the tree.

With a children array you need a function `getChild` for testing if a child is present.

<sub>A note, the supplied data does not keep the identifier unique.</sub>

**Solution A with arrays for children:**

```js
function Node(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.children = []; // array
}

Node.prototype.getChild = function (id) {
    var node;
    this.children.some(function (n) {
        if (n.id === id) {
            node = n;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return node;
};

var path = ['A-->B-->C-->D-->E', 'A-->B-->C-->D-->F', 'A-->F-->C-->D-->E'],
    tree = new Node('root');

path.forEach(function (a) {
    var parts = a.split('-->');
    parts.reduce(function (r, b) {
        var node = r.getChild(b);
        if (!node) {
            node = new Node(b);
            r.children.push(node);
        }
        return node;
    }, tree);
});

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

**Solution B with objects for children:**

```js
function Node(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.children = {}; // object
}

var path = ['A-->B-->C-->D-->E', 'A-->B-->C-->D-->F', 'A-->F-->C-->D-->E'],
    tree = new Node('root');

path.forEach(function (a) {
    var parts = a.split('-->');
    parts.reduce(function (r, b) {
        if (!r.children[b]) {
            r.children[b] = new Node(b);
        }
        return r.children[b];
    }, tree);
});

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Both proposals uses [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for iterating the given strings and for returning the reference to the actual id. If an id is not found, a new instance of node is taken and added to the array or object. The reference is returned for the next id check.

Comment: I see that you are not satisfied with the `console.log()` and started using a cooler display method for the nested thingys. (+) for your solutions.

Comment: @Redu, yes, the area is to small to show bigger data structure.